# Can not connect to my mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have been recently using "localhost" as my mysql database, and now i want to update my website to web.

I took free hosting at "serversfree.com" and uploaded all my web files there.Now i have problem.I made mysql database on that website, and uploaded my mysql database from localhost.

I can go to that server and list all files i have in that mysql database, but when i want to connect my .php documents i don't know how.What to put under "hostname" (i was recently using only localhost).Do i need to put a link where my web mysql database is?

[image]

Or i need to put a link where my website is?

[image]

I tried both but didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most web hosts I've used have MySQL running on the same box so I usually can keep localhost as the server.

Your host should have some documentation on where to point the server to.

Comment: Someone online posted saying they are using "mysql.serversfree.com"

Answer (score 0):

Check if your database credentials, are from a valid user in that database..

Answer (score 0):

What hostname did you use to upload your mysql database from localhost? It would be the same hostname. Probably `mysql.serversfree.com`. If their mysql server is on the same subdomain then you can use `localhost` as well. To connect your php scripts to a mysql server you need to use the hostname of the mysql server, not the hostname of your http server.

Answer (score 0):

If your mysql is running in the same server then you can use localhost or 127.0.0.1 but if mysql is in another server probably you need remote connections